# Preserving picture size after saving Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

After inserting a picture into Excel and scaling it to 20%, the properties show up as:

[image]

After saving the file and reopening it, the properties show up as:

[image]

As seen, the original size of the picture changes to the scaled size after saving.

Is there a way to preserve the original size of the image across file save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Keeping all images in full resolution

This can be changed on a per-workbook basis by going into *File* -> *Options* -> *Advanced* and then scrolling down to *Image Size and Quality*. Select *Do not compress images in file*.

[image: Screenshot of Excel Options]

## Keeping only some images in full resolution

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this on a per-image basis, so you will need to manually compress any **other** images that you **don't** need at full resolution.

If you are inserting many pictures, the quickest way to do this is:

1. Insert all pictures that **do not** need to keep their original resolution
2. Save
3. Insert any pictures that **do** need to keep their original resolution
4. *File* -> *Options* -> *Advanced* -> *Do not compress images in file*
5. Save again

If you only have a few pictures, you can alternatively click on the image you would like to compress and select *Format* -> *Compress Pictures*.

[image: Ribbon bar with Format tab]

In the *Compress Pictures* window, ensure that *Apply only to this picture* is checked and select the resolution that works best for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the info, another way to do it would be to insert link to image. This option shows up in the insert picture dialog.

Answer (score 0):

usually happens when you copy/paste from another source like Photoshop. Copy the image again and "Paste As" > Bitmap